# Uploading pdf file from Django Admin so that Public users can download from frontend

Tags: python, django, pdf, web-applications, django-admin

I am trying to upload a `pdf` file from django Admin side so that users can download it from frontend after registering on website is there any way to do that or any third party package for this task.

> note: I am new to django

Edit:
***project structure:***

```
  ── myproject/
       ├── __init__.py
       ├── settings/
       ├── urls.py
       │__ wsgi.py

  ── myapp/
     └──| __init__.py
        |__ admin.py
        |__ apps.py
        |__ forms.py
        |__ models.py
        |__ tests.py
        |__ urls.py
        |__ views.py

  ── media_cdn/
     ├── static
           |__ media

  ── static/
       ├── css
       └── js
       |__ media

  ── templates
       |__ index.html
```

***myproject/settings.py***

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
    ]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')
```

***myapp/models.py***

```
class My_model(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='static/media')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

***myapp/urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),

   url(r'^download/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

   ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

***myapp/admin.py***

```
from accounts import models

admin.site.register(models.My_model)
```

***myapp/views.py***

```
def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

***index.html***

```
<a href="{{ my_Model_instance.pdf.url }}" download>Click here to download PDF</a>
```

When I click the link on frontend it just downloads the whole page as `HTML` file

but, when I hard code the `url` (for downloading `test123.pdf` as an example)

```
<a href="/static/media/test123.pdf" download>Click here to download PDF</a>
```

it downloads (but here problem is `my_Model` uploads file from `django admin` in `media_cdn/static/media/`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a model :

```
class My_model(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='special location or name')
```

from admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app import models

admin.site.register(models.My_model)
```

and you can access it like in a view :

```
<a href="{{ my_Model_instance.pdf.url }}">Click here to download PDF</a>
```

Comment: Tried your method but its showing `OperationalError `  `no such table` error.

Comment: you need to type : `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: nothing is happening when I click the link <a href="{{ my_Model_instance.pdf.url }}">Click here to download PDF</a> in template.

Comment: can you edit your post and add more detail plz like the html part and view part plz :)

Comment: Edited the post please take a look

Comment: I think you have a little problem here, i think you uploaded your file before changing `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')`, `MEDIA_ROOT` is the folder where uploaded files lives :), dont use static folder its a bad practice because you need to do a `python manage.py collectstatic`.