# Upload PDF File via Django Admin, Users Download from Link on Template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to allow users to download a PDF file that I've previously uploaded to the `MEDIA_ROOT` folder via the admin console. I've emulated the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020362/uploading-pdf-file-from-django-admin-so-that-public-users-can-download-from-fron), however it's incomplete and I can't figure out how to fix this. Hoping someone can spot my issue in the code below.

**settings.py**

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR) + "/media/"

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory that holds static files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR) + "/static/"

# URL that handles the static files served from STATIC_ROOT.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ResumeModel(models.Model):
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to="resume_app/media/resume/")
# So this file gets uploaded to root > media > resume_app > media > resume
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ResumeModel

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(ResumeModel)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ResumeModel

# Create your views here.
def resume(request):
    resume = ResumeModel.objects.all() # < Not sure if this part is needed?
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context={'resume':resume})
```

**template.html**

```
...
<a href="{{ resume.pdf.url }}">Click here to download PDF</a>
...
```

When I hover over this link, the url it's pointing to is `localhost:8083/resume/`, which is the name of the page we're currently on, so I think the `<a href="{{ resume.pdf.url }}">` is not pointing to the correct url of the PDF file I've uploaded. The upload DOES work, the file IS in the `root > media > resume_app > media > resume` folder. What do I need to make the link work?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of @tonio below, and apart from my oversight, I changed the line(s):

```
def resume(request):
    resume = ResumeModel.objects.all() # < Not sure if this part is needed?
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context={'resume':resume})
```

to

```
def resume(request):
    resume =  ResumeModel.objects.last()
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context={'resume':resume})
```

...which is fine for me as I will only have 1 resume in there, and the last entry will be the most recent upload. I then went into that app's folder, and deleted the `__pycache__` and `migrations` folders, performed `python manage.py makemigrations resume_app` and `python manage.py migrate resume_app`, restarted the server, opened app in incognito window and it worked as desired!

Comment: My django is little bit rusty, but I think you need to link/href directly to the resume file name. So let say at the file name is abc.pdf, you need to have your href point out to /media/resume/abc.pdf 

This would mean, I assume, you need to save your file name.

Comment: @sgd I wondered about that too as that's what they did in the other post, and I CAN do that, but I think the idea behind media files is that you can use `{{object.attribute.url}}` syntax in the template to render whatever you want. As an example, I upload images for blog posts using the same methodology, and render them with `src="{{ blog.image.url }}"` and it works just fine, although for those I'm using the `ImageField` function for them, rather than `FileField` for the PDF. Seems weird why this isn't working, I'm just not seein' it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending all resume objects stored in the database to the template:

```py
resume = ResumeModel.objects.all()
```

You can send an specific resume identified by their primary key (see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404)):

```py
def resume(request, resume_id):
    resume =  get_object_or_404(ResumeModel, resume_id)
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context={'resume':resume})
```

Anyway, you can test the template sending the first resume in the database:

```
def resume(request):
    resume =  ResumeModel.objects.first()
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context={'resume':resume})
```

Comment: I have just discovered that the pdf file itself IS uploading to the correct folder, however it's NOT adding a new entry into the database! If you know what might be causing that let me know here, otherwise I'll keep digging on this newly found issue. Maybe something with the `models.FileField(}` syntax?

Comment: @MattWilson, the `FileField` seems Ok. You can't see the list of created objects in the Django admin site?